# React Hooks (Functional) Lifecycle: Component rendered before useEffect() code

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React Functional Components. I'm familiar with the class lifecycle, but not with the functional lifecycle. My problem is that this component is rendered *before* the initialization performed in **useEffect()..** is complete. In my `return()` I check whether a state variable is true or not.

1. I see my non-Error layout first (`TopNav` & `Main`)
2. In 2-3 sec. the screen changes to the `Error` layout

What is the order in which functional components are processed? I can't present then non-Error layout until the error condition has been evaluated.

```
function App() {

    const [error, setError] = useState({});
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});

    const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
       const url = 'http://myapp.com/fetchUserInfo';
       try {
          const response = await axios.get(url);
          setUserInfo(response.data);
       }
       catch (error) { 
          setError(error);
       }
    }  

    // On initialization, fetch UserInfo
    useEffect(() => {    
        fetchUserInfo();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Header />
                
                {error.message
                    ? 
                        <Error error={error} /> 
                    :
                        <div>
                            <TopNav userInfo={userInfo} />
                            <Main userInfo={userInfo} />
                        </div>
                }
                
                <Footer />
            </Router>
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: React component lifecycle is react component lifecycle. It's not any difference between class-based and functional components. Both `componentDidMount` and `useEffect` hook run at the end of the render. If you have some initial pending condition when the component mounts then your UI should account for this, i.e. some loading state or applied conditional rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` callback function is called after the render cycle and so once your render is complete, your `fetchUserInfo` call is made which is again an async operation.

What you should instead have is a loading state to let the UI wait will the API has provided as response to show an appropriate UI

```
function App() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState({});
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});

    const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
       const url = 'http://myapp.com/fetchUserInfo';
       setIsLoading(true);
       try {
          const response = await axios.get(url);
          setUserInfo(response.data);
       }
       catch (error) { 
          setError(error);
       }
       finally {
           setIsLoading(false);
       }
    }  

    // On initialization, fetch UserInfo
    useEffect(() => {    
        fetchUserInfo();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Header />
                
                {isLoading? <Loader />: error.message
                    ? 
                        <Error error={error} /> 
                    :
                        <div>
                            <TopNav userInfo={userInfo} />
                            <Main userInfo={userInfo} />
                        </div>
                }
                
                <Footer />
            </Router>
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: One note, `finally {..}` rather than `finally()`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you will only get an error/data state after the async function `fetchUserInfo` is resolved/rejected. You can try adding a third state `loading` to signify that component has mounted but data fetching is in progress.

```
function App() {

  const [error, setError] = useState({});
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError({})
    const url = 'http://myapp.com/fetchUserInfo';
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      setLoading(false);
      setUserInfo(response.data);
    }
    catch (error) {
      setLoading(false)
      setError(error);
    }
  }

  // On initialization, fetch UserInfo
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserInfo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />

        {error.message && !loading
          ?
          <Error error={error} />
          :
          <div>
            <TopNav userInfo={userInfo} />
            <Main userInfo={userInfo} />
          </div>
        }

        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. It can be cleaned up a bit with `finally` to avoid multiple set calls as per "Shuham Katri".

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be executed in this order.

1. Since the error.message is empty for your first render, the TopNav and Main will be rendered.
2. Execute the useEffect hook, call the fetchUserInfo function. either the error or the userInfo will be updated.
3. Since the state has been changed, will render the page again.
   in your case, it will evaluate the error.message and render the corresponding component.